# AJAX is not calling controller method in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here is some code that I have in my blade layout file. This blade file is called several times in my view like this @include.layout("blade file link"). When a button is pressed I would like my controller function to be called. This works without AJAX. However, when I add AJAX to the mix it does not work.

Below is the code in the blade layout file

```
<div class="element1">
    <div class="text1">
        <form action="{{ route("progressSheetDynamic") }}" method="post" id="addActivity">
            <button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" name="increment" value="increment" > + </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value= {{ $activities}}>
        </form>

        {{ $count  }} / {{  ($goal/5) }}
        <form action="{{route("progressSheetDynamic") }}" method="post" id="removeActivity">
            <button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" name="delete" value="delete"> - </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value= {{ $activities }}>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in my routes.php file.

```
Route::post(
    "progressSheetDynamic",
    [
        "as" => "progressSheetDynamic",
        "uses" => "tableController@addDeleteActivity"
    ]
);

Route::get("progressSheetDynamic", "tableController@getProgressSheetDynamic");
```

Everything is working up to this point, when I press a button `addDeleteActivity` function is called in my controller. Now when I add in the AJAX everything falls apart.

Javascript code with ajax below

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });
});

$('#addActivity').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function(response){
        console.log(data);
    });
});

$('#removeActivity').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function(response){
        console.log("deleting");
    });
}); 
</script>
```

The console.logs work inside the $.post function for both buttons. However, the addDeleteActivity function in the controller is no longer getting called.

Comment: I didn't use Laravel yet, but I think the `{{ route("progressSheetDynamic") }}` in the template generates a URL, but in your post call you simply make a call to the progressSheetDynamic URL, which isn't what you need.
Is the script in the same template file, if this is the case, then try to change the post call to: `$.post('{{ route("progressSheetDynamic") }}', data)`

Comment: I tried this and I get the same result. I actually am surprised that I do get the same result because the post url should get added to the standard url. passing in 'progressSheetDynamic' in the url should give me back  myappurl/progressSheetDynamic. That is my understanding.

Comment: Check your console and your network tab. Is the call being made? Is it returning a 200 message, or 404/405?

Comment: The call is being made I am seeing logs in my console

Comment: Did you tried to console.log the response and what is the response from the server?

Comment: When I console log the response I get a lot of html code back. The html code for the current page

Comment: The network tab is also returning a 200 message

Comment: Is there any error in the response about the CSRF token?

Comment: The CSRF token code at the top portion of the script tag has to do with enabling ajax. If it wasn't there laravel wouldn't allow the ajax request, I am not sure how to see any error response that it might give back.

Comment: I know why is it there, but I think there is something non-printable character in it and that is invalidate it but this just a tip.
Did you tried to change the route name for the post method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110855/discussion-between-fopi-and-ray).

Comment: in your tab Network, the URL where is done request match with your route? the action in your form tag is unneccessary as you set the url in your javascript code

Comment: is this under initiator in chrome ?

Comment: What do you mean with initiator? Chrome has a console to debug, right click to inspect and there is a tab called Network

Comment: initiator is a column in the network tab. the name matches the url

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the URL is the same, you can set same way you're doing without AJAX,

Try this:

```
$('#addActivity').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('{{ route("progressSheetDynamic")' }}, data).done(function(response){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: yea I think thats what FoPi suggested. I tried that its the same

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?